# Perl script with options

Tags: perl, shell

I am looking for a Perl script which does the following:

1. takes two options, like `script.pl -option1 -option2`
2. Option 1 has two choices, say `choice1` and `choice2` and I have shell code
   to do both actions (which I hope I can port to Perl)
3. Here option 2 is the path and is optional. If it's not specified it uses the current directory

#### Desired script

```
checks arguments

if choice 1 :

go to path (arg2)

run a code (i have it ready)

If choice 2

 go to path (arg2 )
 
 run a code
```

Comment: And what is your question? Also, why did you tag with _regex_?

Comment: This module `use Getopt::Long;` will help for your option point with @choroba solution.

Comment: As stated, the question doesn't make much sense. With the given command line, how do you supply the values for `choice1` and `choice2`?

Comment: script.pl action path   this is how scripts is run ,   Eg: script.pl  enable  /home/user

Comment: What have you tried?  Questions of the form "please write my code for me" are off-topic, but if you can show us some (valid or nearly valid) Perl you've started writing and ask a specific question about it we can help with that.  (Or you could send me $100 and I could convert your `sh` code to Perl for you, of course).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

(not tested)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($action, $path) = @ARGV;
$path //= '.';
chdir $path or die "Cannot chdir to $path.\n";

my $script = {
    choice1 => 'script1.sh',
    choice2 => 'script2.sh',
}->{$action};

die "Invalid choice $action.\n" unless defined $script;
0 == system $script or die "Status: $?";
```

Run as `script.pl choice1 /path`.

Comment: Thanks will give a try. though i guess it doesn't take care of option 2 is path and is optional if its not specified it takes cwd as path

Comment: @user2047036: If option 2 is not specified, dot will be assigned to $path, which is equivalent to cwd.

Comment: Thanks , I will give it a try . just started to learn perl a bit